# SVG треугольник - сепаратор с фоновым изображением

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Я пытаюсь создать разделитель фона на основе путей SVG. Он работает, следующим образом:

```html
<section id="section1">
</section>
<svg width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z" />
</svg>
<section id="section2">
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все идет нормально. Но теперь, я хочу,  добавить фон к `section1`, в том числе применить SVG , в примере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот всё, что я сделал (действительно плохие результаты):

Добавил:

`background: url(img)` к элементу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и добавил  `background` к `section1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перевод вопроса: [SVG triangle separator with image background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127198/svg-triangle-separator-with-image-background/38129189#38129189) @[Jorge Anzola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4777323/jorge-anzola)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127198/svg-triangle-separator-with-image-background/38129189#38129189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с использованием `clip-path`

Поддержка браузерами - http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
.element:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;;
  height: 100px;
  background: #2980B9;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 75%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 75%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clippath");
  clip-path: url("#clippath");
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clippath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">    
      <polygon points="0.5 0.75, 1 0, 1 1, 0 100, 0 0" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Использование вариантов: clip-path, mask хоть в CSS или SVG напрашиваются само собой. Но это просто обрезка изображения. А как быть, если нужно сделать область полупрозрачной или эти треугольники анимировать. Я думаю у автора именно такие были мысли. Ведь это не оформление бордюров изображения, а какая-то веб страничка. В любом случае, soledar10 спасибо!

Comment: Изображение не резалось, снизу добавляем с помощью псевдоэлемента блок и его непосредственно преобразуем с помощью clip-path

Comment: Пример с градиентом - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/34yt7fk6/

Comment: Нормально пример с градиентами в Chrome и FF работает. Но clip-path не хочет работать в FF, не смотря на обещания caniuse. Может префиксы на FF надо?

Comment: Посмотрел внимательней caniuse - Partial support refers to only supporting the url() syntax.

Comment: Добавил пример, который работает в FF

Comment: На мой взгляд этот ответ + вариант jsfiddle - лучший ответ

Answer (score 7):

Вот подход, использующий тот же код, что и в вашем примере, но путь `svg` изменен на инвертированный треугольник, который  абсолютно позиционирован в нижней части `section`:

```css
#section1{
  position:relative;
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  height:200px;
}
svg{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-10px; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1">
  <svg width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 0 L50 90 L100 0 V100 H0" fill="#2A80B9" />
  </svg>
</section>
```

Перевод ответа: [SVG triangle separator with image background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127198/svg-triangle-separator-with-image-background/38129189#38129189) @[web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с использованием `before` и `after`:

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.element:before, .element:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2A80B9;
}

.element:before {
    left: -50px;
    bottom: -86%;
    transform: rotate(16deg);
}

.element:after {
    right: -50px;
    bottom: -86%;
    transform: rotate(-16deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Еще как вариант

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.element:before,
.element:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

.element:before {  
  left: 0;
  border-width: 100px 0 0 55vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
}

.element:after {  
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 100px 55vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: soledar10!  И даже на несколько строчек короче, чем у Юрия  А если - вариант - " Например применить другую форму svg path, сделать область перекрытия полупрозрачной, анимировать её при наведение и т.д "

Comment: @Yuri     ну пусть будет на одну :-)

Comment: @Alexandr_T, незадача, не на одну :)

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с использованием градиента:

```css
.element {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(-164deg, transparent 72%, #2A80B9 72%, #2A80B9 100%), linear-gradient(164deg, transparent 72%, #2A80B9 72%, #2A80B9 100%), url(http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg);
  background-size: auto, auto, cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: Замечательно. Оба варианта Yuri  решают вопрос автора с enSO  Хотелось бы еще вариантов для расширения базы знаний ruSO, что нибудь интересное, необязательно точь в точь, по форме,  как я писал в первом комментарии к вопросу enSO.

Comment: У меня градиент отображается с рваными краями. (Хром, Мак ОС)

Comment: @YozhEzhi, и что? Добавь немного переливания на граница и края будут нормальные